# How to efficiently compare Sets?

Tags: java, set, comparable

Given two Sets: how to compare them efficiently in Java?

- (a) keep them as `List`s, sort them and compare them. (`Comparable`)
- (b) keep them as `Set`s and compare the `hashCode` of the Sets?

**background:**

many comparisons need to be done
Sets are small (usually < 5 elements per set).

Comment: `set1.equals(set2);` returns true if the 2 sets contain the same elements...

Comment: thank you for this answer. but is this more efficient than keeping the sets in lists and sorting them + comparsion?

Comment: Are you implementing Set yourself? Because the existing all have `equals` already? Or are you talking about comparing them for ordering (if so, explain how that is supposed to work)?

Comment: no. actually i can keep my "data" in sets or lists. i just want to compare sets (e.g. two hashsets, treesets etc) whatever is most efficient. and i wonder how to compare them in an efficient way.

Comment: The two ways you said will very possibly give different results - and I think that sets naturally aren't comparable......

Comment: What do you mean by compare? See if they are equal (i.e. contain equal elements)? Or see which one "comes first"/"is greater"?

Comment: no they won't. and sets are comparable. (every element of setA is contained in setB and vice-versa)...

Comment: They are comparable in terms of equality, but if you want to order the sets then you would need some way to rank one set against another.

Comment: if you mean "every element of setA is contained in setB " use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: ok sorry my fault. I should have defined compare before: I would like to check weather the two sets consist of exactly the same elements.

Answer (score 9):

The proper way to compare two sets is to use [the `equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). I would not worry about performance unless you have proven that this is a part of your code that is causing performance issue (which I doubt). And considering the size of your sets (5 elements) this will be very fast (probably sub millisecond).

> keep them as lists, sort them and compare them. (comparable)

will certainly be slower as you will need to copy the elements, sort them and compare.

> keep them as sets and compare the hashcode of the sets?

if 2 sets are equal (have the same content) they will have the same hashcode. The reciprocal is not true: 2 sets with different content may have the same hashcode. Also note that for a `HashSet` for example, the hashcode is calculated by iterating over all the elements so it is not a free operation.

Comment: Sub-millisecond would be slow.  There is a good chance that it will be sub-microsecond, and even less if sets are unequal most of the time.

Comment: For HashSets this boils down to five hash lookups; for the dumbest approach imaginable, two five-element lists, this would still only entail a worst case of 25 `equals` comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with  [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)? 
The docs states that it returns true if both are of same size and if `containsAll()` returns true, sounds pretty efficient to me.

In any case, you should *never* compare the hashcode to test for equality, two different objects might have the same hashcode.

*Update:* As noted in the comments (and in assylias' answer) the hashcode can be used as part of the equality test logic (different hashcodes imply different objects - but not the reverse). My remark above means that the hashcode alone is not (in general) enough.

Comment: -1 for the hashcode remark. If you have a hashcode readily available, you should use it. Because if the codes differ, the objects are not equal. That is how String#equals is implemented. (Of course, if the hashcodes are equal, that tells you nothing).

Comment: @Thilo Actually in the case of a set, the hashcode is not cached like in String, so its computation requires a loop over each element.

Comment: Yes, the hashcode is probably not cached in a Set (you cannot really say, because Set is an interface, in an immutable Set it might well be). But Set should look at size() first, which works pretty much in the same way.

Comment: Though improperly stated, the hashcode of a set should ***absolutely*** not be used to make a determination about its equality to another set. An edit is in order but not a down vote, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do a comparison whether `set1`  has *exactly the same* elements of `set2`.

`set1.equals(set2)` and also `set2.equals(set1)` as to make sure both are *exactly the same*.

Comment: Only one comparison is necessary. Equals is symmetric: `set1.equals(set2)` will always return the same result as `set2.equals(set1)` (unless one of them is null of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `HashSet`s, comparing them by `Set.equals` will be O(n) because only one set needs to be iterated through, and the other will be checked by `contains`, which is itself O(1).

Note that for sets as small as yours the difference between O(n) and O(n<sup>2</sup>) is neglible, so even the naïvest approaches will yield good performance.